# Python3: tempfile.mkstemp file gets deleted on its own

Tags: python, python-3.x, temporary-files

I'm using `tempfile.mkstemp(dir=tempdir.name, prefix="out_")` to create a bunch of temporary files.

`tempdir` was created as a `tempdir.TemporaryDirectory(dir="/asdf")`.

Despite the fact that the documentation says that the user is responsible for deleting these files, which I don't do, and don't want, all my temporary files are gone after the Python process exits. Is this intentional? How can I fix this?

For debugging purposes, I want to keep these files around after the process closes.

Comment: Show more context. What ist `tempdir.name`?

Answer (score 0):

I created all temporary files in a `TemporaryDirectory`. Even without using a context manager, `TemporaryDirectory` calls `shutil.rmdir` on all its contents (i.e., cleans itself and all its contents no matter what files it contains) when it is garbage collected.